# Conditional statement in server.R

Tags: r, shiny

Not sure what wrong I am doing here. Since the length(key) is 0, I need to assign the value of `selectedInput` to `key_as`. If the length(key) is not 0, then `key_as` should be "a"

For example, in this case, since length(key) = 0, whatever the user selectes from dropdown (say "A"), the key_as should be "A". But if length(key) !=0 then the value of key_as should be "a" (The value of key_1)

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("edit_condition")
        )
    )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    columnNames <- c("A","B","C")
    key <- c()  # This is just an example
    key_1 <- c("a")
    # print(length(key))

    if(length(key) == 0){
        output$edit_condition <- renderUI({
            selectInput("ed", "Condition", choices = c(columnNames), selected = columnNames[[1]])
        })
        key_as <- input$ed
    } else {
        key_as <- key_1
    }

    print(key_as)
})
```

Tried solution

```
    key_as <- reactive({
        if(length(key) == 0){
            input$ed
        } else {
            key_1
        }
    })
```

Comment: Hi all, Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Sure. Thanks. I have edited my question. however key = c() was an example thats it. let me know if this makes sense :)

Comment: key is not depending on any UI. And yes key_as is used in the end in the server. So it depends on dropdown input. Make sense? Do not worry about key. It is just for a an example. Key can be anything. But key_as should be as selected from dropdown

Comment: Yes your right. Colnames will change. Colnames depends on the data. Is it now making sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you have in mind, but maybe this will help in further discussion.

You can use an `observeEvent` that will get called when `input$ed` changes. You can also have `reactiveValues` for `key_as` and `column_names` so both can change with inputs.

Let me know if this is closer.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(key_as = NULL, column_names = c("A","B","C"))

  observeEvent(input$ed, {
    key <- c()
    key_1 <- c("a")

    if(length(key) == 0){
      rv$key_as <- input$ed
    } else {
      rv$key_as <- key_1
    }

    print(rv$key_as)
  })

  output$edit_condition <- renderUI({
    selectInput("ed", "Condition", choices = rv$column_names, selected = rv$column_names[[1]])
  })

})
```

Here is a complete example, that will print the `rv$key_as` in an output as the `selectInput` changes:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("edit_condition"),
      textOutput("text_output")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(key_as = NULL, column_names = c("A","B","C"))

  observeEvent(input$ed, {
    key <- c()
    key_1 <- c("a")

    if(length(key) == 0){
      rv$key_as <- input$ed
    } else {
      rv$key_as <- key_1
    }

    print(rv$key_as)
  })

  output$text_output <- renderText({
    rv$key_as
  })

  output$edit_condition <- renderUI({
    selectInput("ed", "Condition", choices = rv$column_names, selected = rv$column_names[[1]])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I did try this actually. But actually you are printing ````print(rv$key_as)```` inside observer right? So, the value is reactive. But if you print(rv$key_as) outside observe event, the application crashes. It means ````rv$key_as```` is not taking values selected from dropdown.

Comment: Thanks, I have put what I have tried in the question. Can we not do like that ? And call key_as at any point in server.R?

Comment: It just is unclear to me what that means: "any point in server.R" ... shiny will run the whole script including server function when you run your app. each new user visits your app, it runs the server function. otherwise, most of the server is built on widgets and interactivity. for example, selectInput that changes values, a plot output that shows a graph, a data table that shows data, etc. generally, i use observe, reactive, and output expressions to use the reactivity with shiny ... the question is, what do you plan to do with `key_as`?

Comment: If you want to read more about shiny, there is the [tutorial from R Studio](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/).